# boolean method does not behave as expected and returns false when true is expected

Tags: java

Here's the code in question:

```
public boolean validMoveRook(int[] start, int[] end) {

    int xDif = end[0]-start[0];
    int yDif = end[1]-start[1];

    if (xDif == 0 ^ yDif == 0) {

        int distance;
        int direction;

        if (xDif == 0) {
            distance = Math.abs(yDif);
            direction = 1;
        }
        else {
            distance = Math.abs(xDif);
            direction = 0;
        }

        for (int i = distance - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (direction == 0) {
                int newX = start[0] + utilities.AbsoluteChange(xDif, -i);
                if (this.board[newX][start[1]] != FREE) return false;
            }
            if (direction == 1) {
                int newY = start[1] + utilities.AbsoluteChange(yDif, -i);
                if (this.board[start[0]][newY] != FREE) return false;
            }

            if (this.board[start[0]][start[1]] == TURN0_WHITEROOK) {
                this.board[start[0]][start[1]] = WHITEROOK;
            }
            if (this.board[start[0]][start[1]] == TURN0_BLACKROOK) {
                this.board[start[0]][start[1]] = BLACKROOK;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("success");
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println("Oh no!");
    return false;
}
```

I'm trying to make a chess game. The issue is that it keeps returning false even when it shouldn't. "success" is printed, but it still returns false. Why is this?

Comment: What is `board`? What is `FREE`? Please post a [MCVE]. Also this appears to be a great opportunity to use your debugging skills and figure out what the problem is

Comment: Did you actually mean `if (xDif == 0 ^ yDif == 0)` ?

Comment: board is the 2d array of characters that acts as the chessboard. FREE is just an unobtrusive symbol that is printed in the empty squares. The AbsoluteChange method takes the absolute value of the first value, adds the second value, and then returns that with the original sign.

Comment: What makes you think it is returning false? The fact that the `println` and the `return true;` are two consecutive lines makes me think that either the printing is happening somewhere else or the method really is returning true

Comment: I'm printing the result of calling the method and it's printing false. I also have a do-while loop in another class which checks if the move is valid and it's not moving on.

Comment: I would suggest running the code with just the code necessary to call this method and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gblodgett pointed out, it's quite possible that you have a `Sop("success")` in your `utilities.AbsoluteChange` method and the `false` is being returned just after that call.